# How do I create a network share on Windows XP that has blank credentials?

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares, credentials, share-credentials

I'm trying to create a network share on Windows XP that doesn't save credentials so that a blank username and password dialog box is presented to each person that wants to use it.
I don't want to leave the share open to everyone.

The share is on a domain but the computer that has this share isn't.

The users have their own domain account that they'll use for this.

So far I've managed to create a networked drive without a saved password, but I don't want to present that username every time someone wants to use this share because if they're not careful and hit enter they could lock it out.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blank password is not allowed for this. If you want it to have no password, it can't have a log in as such either (the log in process cannot be having the user type something in. If it is a part of a domain, then you have other options, but that does not seem to be the case here).

Comment: I don't want a blank password, I just want the share to prompt for one.

Comment: Can't do it. It's a security flaw, so not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the "everyone" group to a share in order to provide open access. (or is it everybody? they really should just add all synonyms to that)

Answer (score 0):

This just sounds like a weird situation.  The host isn't part of the domain, but the share is? Don't you mean, the computer isn't in the domain, but they are on the same physical network as everyone?

Have you tried changing the network settings to where everyone has to logon as a guest?